# How do I print lines from a command-line input file to a command-line output file?

Tags: java, input, output, command-line-arguments, bluej

the input file has lines of text like this:

```
allison wesley 28011990

peter smith 05071992
```

and my code (to try and print this to an output file) is the following(im providing both the input and output as command-line args):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FormatNames{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(args[0]);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(args[1]);
        while(in.hasNext()){
            String str = in.next();
            out.print(""+str);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?
At the moment, the only thing it outputs to the file is the name of the input file

Thanks

Comment: Reading the documentation helps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 3):

You are using the Scanner constructor that takes a String as input: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)

Try to use the constructor that takes a File like:

```
new Scanner(new File(arg[0]));
```